# Generic Method Argument Type Not Recognized?

Tags: c#, generics

This is probably due to my terrible understanding of generic methods, so I apologize in advance.

I am trying to write a csvWriter class that inherits from StreamWriter. One method I want it to have is to take a collection like an array or list and use String.Join to change it into a comma separated string, and then to write it as usual. I thought it would be simple, and if I use method overloading it is, but I am used to python and the idea of generics feels better to me, so I was giving it a shot.

However, my attempt is not working. The method doesn't seem to know what type is being passed to it, or something?

Class:

```
public class csvWriter : System.IO.StreamWriter
    {
        public csvWriter(string filename) : base(filename)
        {
        }

        public void WriteLineFromCollection<T>(T line)
        {
            string newLine = String.Join(",", line);
            base.WriteLine(newLine);
        }
    }
```

Lines to call it:

```
using (var reader = new csvReader(filename_in))
using (var writer = new csvWriter(filename_out))
            {
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string[] line = reader.ReadLine();
                    writer.WriteLineFromCollection<string[]>(line);
                }
                Console.Out.Write("PAUSE");
            }
```

The file, instead of having the string full of comma-separated values, ends up with "System.String[]." I think that I am actually giving it the type of the argument but not the argument itself, but don't know why this is the case. The debugger from inside WriteLineFromCollection is giving me what feels like conflicting information: 
It says line is of type string[], but when I try line[0] it says "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type T."

Comment: What should it do if you pass it something that is not a collection?

Comment: You need to change the type of `line` to `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: have you tried changing the T to IList<T>?

Comment: @Lee IEnumberable doesn't support indexing either.

Comment: @Mike_G: He doesn't need indexing. So `IEnumerable<T>` would be entirely appropriate (even preferable) here.

Comment: @MattBurland my mistake, from his post "when I try line[0] ", I assumed he was needing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In you function you are using `string[]` as your generic type argument, but your function knows nothing about what you are passing in other than it's an object (you have no type restriction). So you code has to be able to work with whatever you might pass. Now you are, presumably hoping it will use [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx) overload of `string.Join`:

```
public static string Join(
    string separator,
    IEnumerable<string> values
)
```

since `string[]` implements `IEnumerable<string>`, but the compiler can't do that. It doesn't know if anything about `T` at all. All it knows is that it's an object. So the only overload of it can use is [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988350(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static string Join(
    string separator,
    params Object[] values
)
```

Now because of the `params` keyword here, you don't have to pass an `Object[]` explictly, you can just pass a bunch of arguments and it'll treat it like an object array. For example, you could do something like this (not to say it's a good idea, because it probably isn't):

```
string.Join(",","somestring",1,true,new object());
```

So what happens when you pass in your `string[]` is basically equivalent to if you'd done this:

```
string.Join("," new object[] { line });
```

Now what that overload does is it will iterate through each item in the object array and call `ToString` on it and then join the results together. Calling `ToString` on a `string[]` will return `System.String[]` as you saw. That's the base implementation of `object.ToString()`, it just returns the type name.

Obviously, this isn't what you want. Something like this should work:

```
public void WriteLineFromCollection<T>(IEnumerable<T> line)
{
    string newLine = String.Join(",", line);
    base.WriteLine(newLine);
}
```

You are using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx) overload of `Join` which takes an `IEnumerable<T>` and will call `ToString()` on each item in your collection.

```
public static string Join<T>(
    string separator,
    IEnumerable<T> values
)
```

So now, when you pass in a collection of `T` (that implements `IEnumerable<T>`, which `string[]` does), it will be treated as a collection and not implicitly wrapped in an object array like before. Now it's iterates through you collection of `T` and calls `ToString`, which in the case of an actual `string` just returns the `string` itself. Note if you passed something other than `string` as your type parameter, then you will get whatever their `ToString` does, which might be just the type name. So you'll probably want to override `ToString` in your own classes to do something sensible if you intend it to be used here.

Of course, you really aren't gaining much out of this versus just inlining a call to `String.Join`, but it might be a little more readable and would at least give you a single place to have to change when somebody decides you should use a different separator.

Note, using `IEnumerable` is preferable to `IList` here if you don't need to index into your collection. That way you could, for example, pass something from linq without having to `ToList` it first.

You can call it simply with:

```
writer.WriteLineFromCollection(line);
```

You don't need to specify `T` explicitly if the compiler can figure it out.

Comment: And just to note, his caller would now look like this: `writer.WriteLineFromCollection<string>(line)` instead of `writer.WriteLineFromCollection<string[]>(line)`  **Edit:** I had my examples backwards

Comment: @Tom: You shouldn't even need to explicitly specify the generic type parameter in most cases.

Comment: Wow, this works, thank you so much. There is some deep magic happening here, and I would be very grateful if you could explain a couple of things:  
**1)** Generally "T" would be the generic placeholder for whatever type I pass in, correct? Is the argument here just basically saying "make an enumerable out of whatever type is passed in"?  
**2)** Why does `WriteLineFromCollection<string>` work? I thought the argument I was passing it was a string[]?     
**3)** In what situation can the compiler not figure it out? Am I not passing in data of some type, which it could then figure out?  
Thanks!

Comment: @Msg: I tired to expand some on my answer for you. 1) yes. 2) You are passing an `IEnumerable<T>`, the type parameter here is the type of things *in* your collection. 3) can't think of an example of the top of my head, but the compiler will let you know if it can't infer the type parameter.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because compiler chooses String.Join overload with 2nd parameter `params object[] value`, so you passes string array as one param. To resolve this you can add constraint to `WriteLineFromCollection` method:

```
public void WriteLineFromCollection<T>(T line) where T : IEnumerable<string>
{
    string newLine = String.Join(",", line);
    base.WriteLine(newLine);
}
```

This will force compiler to choose overload with 2nd parameter of type `IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: In my opinion, he doesn't even really need the generic; this is what interfaces like `IEnumerable` exist for - so you can call it with anything that implements the interface. My version: `public void WriteLineFromCollection(IEnumerable<string> line)`

Comment: The `string` is what he wants generic, this ties him to a `string` -- I believe he wants to pass anything, like a list of integers, or strings, or chars, or whatever

Comment: If you are going to use `where T : IEnumerable<string>` you might as well just make it `WriteLineFromCollection(IEnumerable<string> line)`. You gain nothing for generics in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try changing from `public void WriteLineFromCollection<T>(T line)` to `public void WriteLineFromCollection<IList<T>>(IList<T> line)`

if you want to support indexing, or as Sergey mentioned, add a constraint.

Answer (score 0):

There is little problem with the approch of your code, as the only type that will be passed is String makes this as abuse use of Genrics...
Prehapes you want to write an Extenstion method to string type that the out put will be the CSV formatted string?